# jQuery Email Address Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, email, input

I'd like an autocomplete/autoformat "To" field on my web site that works like the one in GMail.

Does anyone know of such a thing for jQuery?

Plain JavaScript?  Or any other alternatives?

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted it and replaced it with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots and lots of jquery bits that do this, you can google for "jquery autocomplete" and see which you like best.

Here's one that is more famous: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/AutoComplete

```
<script>
    var emails = [
        { name: "Kitty Sanchez", to: "kanchez@bluth.com" },
        { name: "Lucille Austero", to: "lucille2@balboatowers.net" },
        { name: "Bob Loblaw", to: "bloblaw@bobloblawlawblog.com" },
        { name: "Sally Sitwell", to: "sally@sitwell.org" }
    ];

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Recipients").autocomplete(emails, {
            multiple: true,
            minChars: 1,
            matchContains: "word",
            autoFill: false,
            formatItem: function(row, i, max) {
                return "\"" + row.name + "\" &lt;" + row.to + "&gt;";
            },
            formatMatch: function(row) {
                return row.name + " " + row.to;
            },
            formatResult: function(row, i, max) {
                return "\"" + row.name + "\" <" + row.to + ">";
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Check out this plugin. It appears to be quite robust and stable and may meet your needs. jQuery is a perfect choice for the kind of effect your seeking. Just keep in mind that, depending on where you want to get your data from, you'll need to create some sort of ajax/php backend.

Comment: I'd remove the php part as any server-side web technology/framework could be used

Answer (score 1):

These answers are fine but I think he's looking for something email specific. Gmail's email auto complete is very robust and smart taking into account like who you email most often and other factors.

Comment: You could probably figure something primitive in for this on the backend, assuming that there is auditng for sending emails and you know who sent an email and who they sent it to.