# Best UX for list like content that lives inside a data grid

Tags: autocomplete, user-experience

Would love any advice on UX practices / UI ideas for allowing users to quickly enter lists of values in a single spreadsheet cell that represent something related to a specific line and can be picked from a finite set of admissible values. So far the best I can conceive is a textInput with autocomplete functionality - similar to [this one](http://examples.adobe.com/flex2/exchange/AutoComplete/AutoCompleteCountriesData/AutoCompleteCountriesData.html) but with the autocomplete functionality working for each of the values being entered in the cell. I'm very open to suggestions though...

thanks

f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about how gmail does autocomplete per name when addressing email? Apple Mail does something similar, but has a better UI IMO. Check out [jQuery Email Address Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533761/jquery-email-address-input) for some more info.

Comment: Ben, I think that may work. The only minor difference - for which there may be no great solution - is that in my case I'd like the list of possible options to be finite. In other words, while in email one can add a new address, in my spec the list of values from which to choose is finite. Not sure how to best handle the case of someone trying to enter an non-admissible value - whether via visual feedback after the fact or via not allowing a user to type a wrong value (which seems complicated and may look like an unresponsive UI).

Comment: In that case, you may want to consider a checkbox list. If there are several choices (like say, over 50), then provide a filter box where the list can update as you type (possibly empty). Something like your Facebook `All Friends` list.

Comment: Actually I like a hybrid of the Facebook All Friends list and the gmail addresses. Thank you!